# C++ {fmt} library: Is there a way to format repeated format fields?

Tags: c++, fmt

I have a program with many formatted write statements that I'm using the fmt library for. Some of them have many fields, say 100 for example purposes, something like this:

```
fmt::print(file_stream, "{:15.5g}{:15.5g}{:15.5g}/*and so on*/", arg1, arg2, arg3/*same number of arguments*/);
```

Is there a straightforward way to truncate the fields so they don't all have to be written out? Obviously this example wouldn't work but it illustrates the idea:

```
fmt::print(file_stream, 100("{:15.5g"), arg1, arg2, arg3/*etc*/);
```

Comment: I see nothing in the [Format String Syntax](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html) that would accomodate this. You would likely have to build up a format `std::string` in a loop, and then pass that to `fmt::print()`, etc: `std::string formatstr; for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { formatstr += "{:15.5g}"; } fmt::print(file_stream, formatstr, arg1, arg2, arg3/*etc*/);` Though, I would probably just put all of the values into an array instead, and then loop through the array calling `fmt::print()` on each array element: `for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { fmt::print(file_stream, "{:15.5g}", array[i]); }`

Comment: You could write a function like `repeating_string` and have it take in a string and a number of times to repeat it.  Then in the function you build that string return it so you call site looks like `fmt::print(file_stream, repeating_string("{:15.5g"}, 100), arg1, arg2, arg3/*etc*/);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your arguments in an array and format part of this array as a view (using `span` or similar) with `fmt::join` (https://godbolt.org/z/bo1GrofxW):

```
#include <array>
#include <span>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
  double arg1 = .1, arg2 = .2, arg3 = .3;
  double args[] = {arg1, arg2, arg3};
  fmt::print("{:15.5}", fmt::join(std::span(args, args + 2), ""));
}
```

Output:

```
            0.1            0.2
```